# .htaccess Mod-Rewrite Rule not working?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So right now, I have my website rerouting from www.example.com/username to their profile page, but I want it to reroute from www.example.com/users/username. My code currently is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} >""
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

I have tried using this code, yet it gives me an error saying that the page cannot be found:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteRule ^users/([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} >""
RewriteRule ^users/([^\.]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

I have tried other options, but I cannot seem to get them to work. Will I need an actual /users folder, or should this be redirecting without the use of another folder?

Comment: What does this do? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} >""`. I've never seen that before.

Comment: It's a "lexicographical string comparison" (see about 1/3 down this page) : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html I'm not 100% certain that it makes sense in the way it's being used here though...

Comment: Ok, but what does it do for you? It's just a greater than string comparison right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules in the given order:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^users/([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteRule ^users/([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

Will rewrite `/users/foo.php` to `foo.php` I don't think that's what you want.

---

I think it's as simple as:

```
RewriteRule ^users/(.+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC]
```

If the folder `users` doesn't exist you don't need a `RewriteCond`

If you want `[^\.]+` instead of `.+` that's fine but I don't think you need it.